# Wordpress override thickbox CSS impossible?

Tags: css, wordpress, thickbox

I want to remove

```
#TB_window {
position: fixed;
background: #fff; <== THIS
z-index: 100050;
visibility: hidden;
text-align: left;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 3px 6px rgba( 0, 0, 0, 0.3 );
box-shadow: 0 3px 6px rgba( 0, 0, 0, 0.3 );
}
```

So I just copied that into my .css and set background: transparent; !important

But it is NOT overriding.
I also want to remove the background on #TB_overlay...
There's a trick here because it also has class="TB_overlayBG" so

`#TB_overlay.TB_overlayBG {
background-color: transparent; !important
}`

I can't edit the thickbox.css because it will get overwritten when I update Wordpress.

I have a plugin that uses the thickbox in the post template of a custom post type, like this:

```
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>?TB_iframe=true&width=790&height=578" class="thickbox">
<?php the_post_thumbnail( 'medium-thumb' , array('class' => 'product-image') ); ?>
</a>
```

When I click this image, I get an iframe inside a Thickbox of the post. 
I have a .css that loads with the plugin like this:

```
wp_register_style( 'catalogue-style', plugins_url( 'product-catalogue' ) . '/css/catalogue-style.css' ); 
wp_enqueue_style( 'catalogue-style' );
```

So my catalogue-style.css is first in the page source.
thickbox.css is linked after the footer!

Comment: Can you post a JSFiddle, please ?

Comment: Well no, I don't know how to post a JSFiddle with Wordpress functions and all that.

Comment: Does giving your catalogue-style a higher priority in the add_action (something like 999) have any effect?  Without knowing the specifics of which plugin and seeing the generated output, it's hard to provide further recommendations.

Answer (score 1):

Try overriding it like this instead:

```
#TB-window {
  background:transparent;
}
```

Background is shorthand for lots of background properties including background-color and background-image.  Background-color doesn't accept the value none.  According to the specification, it accepts values of: `<color>` | transparent | inherit.

Background-image does accept none as a property, so if you had an image in the background property that you wanted to override, you could pass the none in.

However, if you pass none to the the background property with a color set, inheritance just takes over and assumes you want the color to be #fff and the image value to be none.  Make sense?

Comment: Hey, thanks for taking your time to answer.
The problem is, there is no way I can override the settings in thickbox.css because it takes highest priority. So even I'm using background-color: transparent; background: transparent; or whatever... If it's specified in thickbox.css those properties can't be changed. So same goes for overlay background-color :(

Comment: Cascade order is cascade order:  You can always override css (well, except for user rules with important attached which isn't the case here).  So, maybe you can explain where you're adding this custom css in WordPress.  Perhaps the part that's causing confusion here.

Comment: Updated original post.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone has the same problem try:

```
div#TB_window {background:none;box-shadow:none;}
```